# Internet Explorer Not Passing Data in Joomla

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla2.5, virtuemart

So check this out. I have a custom module for Joomla 2.5.27 and Virtuemart 2.6.
I can pass the options data for a dash kit application in all browsers except IE. Example: https://superiordash.com/products/dash-kits/index.html?make_id=8&model_id=63&year_id=48&option=com_mmg&view=products&page=list&sel_make_id=-1&sel_model_id=-1&sel_year_id=-1&Itemid=580

This application has an option to choose from a drop down box. You then select your material on the next page. From there you add to cart. The drop down option passes through on all browsers except IE where it doesn't pass the option selected to the cart.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: works fine for me. I'm using IE11.0.9600.17633 with KB3021952 update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3021952. The options I select from the previous pages goes into the next page and into the cart. Can you please elaborate further the issue your experiencing?

Comment: The products are adding correctly. It's the select options that are not passing. 2002 Daewoo Nubira Complete Trim Kit in Argent Silver w/options - Radio: //HERE IS WHERE OPTIONS SHOULD BE\\

Should look like this:
2002 Daewoo Nubira Complete Trim Kit in Argent Silver w/options - Radio: - Single Disc CD

I'm using IE11.0.9600.17631 btw

Comment: IE 8 passes the data. IE 9 and up does not. I don't get it :(.